Who was the "Dutch author", "Bumstone Bumstone"?
In Stephen Leacock's Sunshine Sketches of a Little Town, we have the following description of a minor character:

Mallory Tompkins was a young man with long legs and check trousers who worked on the Mariposa Times-Herald. That was what gave him his literary taste. He used to read Ibsen and that other Dutch author—Bumstone Bumstone, isn't it?—and you can judge that he was a mighty intellectual fellow. He was so intellectual that he was, as he himself admitted, a complete eggnostic.

I suspect that "Bumstone Bumstone" represents a real author, prominent at the time of publication (1912), but I can't guess who is intended.

Since Ibsen is not a Dutch author, it seems like the narrator (but probably not the author) may be a bit confused.

I am a native speaker of Dutch and "Bumstone Bumstone" doesn't even sound remotely like a Dutch name. This could be just satire.

Bjørnstjerne Bjørnson was a Norwegian author who received the 1903 Nobel Prize in Literature, so he definitely qualifies in terms of being prominent.
He is just as Dutch as Henrik Ibsen (i.e., not very), and his name sounds vaguely like Bumstone Bumstone (probably especially if you're an English speaker who doesn't know how to pronounce Dutch Norwegian).

In my experience there is no little confusion, in the United States at least, about the Netherlands, no doubt related to the lack of similarity between "Netherlands" and "Dutch" compounded with the (waning) tendency to refer to the country as "Holland."  There is also occasionally a misconception that the country or the language is Scandinavian, perhaps not helped by the greater similarity between "Netherlands" and "Norway" or "Dutch" and "Danish."  In short, confusion of this sort is not uncommon.

That's brilliant. I love how time turned what probably was a fairly understandable literary inside gag into a completely obscure reference. The wrong country is a nice touch, since it leaves open who of the author or narrator didn't know the difference between the Netherlands and Norway.

Stephen Leacock was from Canada, not the United States. Confusion of this sort is not uncommon.

@phoog Well, at least Bjørnson himself could not have been too offended with being taken for a Dutchman, as he had claimed (according to Wikipedia), "the greatest dream of my life is for the South Germanic peoples and the North Germanic peoples and their brothers in diaspora to unite in a fellow confederation" ;-)

@JonathanZ It seems likely that Leacock was intentionally making his character misidentify the country, so Leacock is probably not himself confused about who is and is not from The Norwaylands, anymore than he was confused about how to spell 'agnostic'.

I was replying to phoog.
